# Fill the date field when clicking on button

Tags: xml, button, odoo-13

I want to change the value of field ( that changes to the date of the day for example), when i click on an existing button and access to that form or tree in odoo 13.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the record before retrieve the form view, update it and then retrieve the view normally.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

EDITED 2022-02-06: Example.

```
def action_your_button(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    # Define a proper domain to find the target record
    domain = [('your_field', '=', 'some_value')]
    record = self.env['your.model'].search(domain, limit=1)  # limit=1 to ensure update only 1 record
    # Update record
    record.write({'field_to_update': new_value})

    action = {
        'name': 'Action Name',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'your.model',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': self.env.ref('your_module_name.your_view_form_id').id,
        'res_id': record.id,
        'target': 'new'
    }
    return action
```

Comment: Could you give me an example, I'm starting and I'm not very knowledgeable. Thankyou

Comment: And if I have to do it from a button already created or when loading a page

Comment: I don't understand what are you refer, the code above should be fired from an action button in your form.

Comment: I mean something automatic or when you access an already created view the action is generated

Comment: That's another question, please elaborate it in other post.